# Programming for Website to appear in Google +

Tags: google-plus

I'm trying to get my website to appear on Google + when I post a link (it works on Facebook, with a description and thumbnail.) and when I try to post anylink from my website, Google + tries to load it for about 10 seconds before showing me this message

Could not load website. - Retry

Anyone know what could be causing this, and how to get rid of it/bypass it?

EDIT: I can't access my server error log, but my website loads perfectly when accessed directly, and Facebook can load it. So I don't think it's the server, exept if google fetches the site in a REALLY weird way. BTW, it's a Wordpress website, with a custom theme I created.

Comment: Check your web server's error log? You're going to need to post more details for anyone to be able to give you a solid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the rich snippets tool: http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/richsnippets to test if your site is accessible to Google.

Often the problems are because your site requires authentication or takes too long to load.

It would also help if you share the link to your site.